# Check for boolean and set variable value or default without using ELSE in Laravel 8 controller

Tags: php, laravel

I need to calculate points based on boolean selections and I'd like to reduce the amount of code by eliminating the `ELSE` part of my statements.

Is there anyway to compress this statement down?

```
...
if ($this->track) { 
   $trackPTS = 20;
} else { 
   $trackPTS = 0;
}
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this:

`$trackPTS = $this->track ? 20 : 0;`